# Why do Sessions disappear on refresh with Laravel 5.x?

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have a simple file where I'm creating sessions, it looks like the following:

```
<?php namespace App\Repositories\Managers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class SessionTest {

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function sessionTest()
    {
        Session::put('test', 111);
        dd(Session::all());
    }
}
```

It gets me the Session right as expected.

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "pYbrTbhnsLx6BfUNZusedQSYiBGxL3t9W7IyRVAh"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "flash" => array:2 [▼
    "old" => []
    "new" => []
  ]
  "test" => 111
]
```

Now for some reason, when I open another page up and display **Session::all()** it gives me back the following:

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "pYbrTbhnsLx6BfUNZusedQSYiBGxL3t9W7IyRVAh"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "flash" => array:2 [▼
    "old" => []
    "new" => []
  ]
]
```

Basically it looks like that it's deleting all the Session storage once I'm opening up a new page.

My session.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path().'/framework/sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'ck_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => false,

];
```

It seems like that the session file is not getting written when I check it. It only stores the default values.

What is the main issue here? Never faced the same before.

Comment: Read permissoin issue maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you assigned write permission correctly (i.e 777) for the storage directory in your application. It maybe causing the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Try this command before dd():

```
Session::save()
```

Session::save() will be automatically called when render to view. In your case, you exit before call this function. So your session wasn't saved

Comment: Well since laravel uses Symfony's HttpFoundation package, there is in fact a save method https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Session/Session.php

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
```

instead of

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

---

```
//to set a session variable use
$session = new Session();
$session->set('variableName', $requestData['key']);

//to get that session variable
$session = new Session();
$session->get('variableName');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I removed the cookies in the JavaScript, so maybe check if you don't use something like this in your .js before you refresh:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setTime(now.getTime()+(-1*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "=;"+" path=/; expires="+now.toUTCString();
document.cookie = "lastpage"+expires;
```